# Open source CMS for building web sites based on asp.net mvc

Tags: web-development, cms, templating

I have being working on building web applications using the following technologies:-

- Asp.net mvc5
- C-sharp
- Entity framework
- Sql server DB.
- Jquery, bootstrap

For my web applications I do not care very much about interface being fancy. I only use some web templates and added it inside the _layout shared view. Now I want to start my first web site project for a construction company. The main sections of the web site are:-

- Standard home, about us, contact us sections. That contain text & pictures.
- Our projects sections. Which have a slide show images and description bout each project.

I am searching for a CMS that provide these capabilities:-

- Ability for end users (non IT people) such as project managers, marketing employees to be able to edit the pages; about us , contact us, etc..
- Ability for non-technical people to add new projects. Where they upload a series of images and provide description.
- Finally to allow me to work smoothly I want a tool which allow me to benefit from my asp.net mvc knowledge.

So can anyone advice on available tools ?

second point . i find many powerful web templates (not CMS) , where i am thinking of building modules for allowing end-users to populate the web template sections. so i can build the CMS functionaries by myself and base my web site on available web templates .. so is this valid approach to consider. i mean using web templetes instead of CMS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Orchard, it's mature, with very active community, packed with features and pretty easy to setup (You can use Web platform installer).

Look at [OrchardProject](http://orchardproject.net/).

Comment: thanks for the reply. but is using a web template, then develop the CMS features using asp.net and bad approach to follow..? i mean t use a web template rather than using CMS ..

Comment: It's not necessary bad, but much much more work. That way you would control all features, but IMO better solution is pick mature and open CMS and work your specific needs on that foundation

Comment: but in my case the work i will be doing is less than learning a new CMS (as i did not work on any before),, and as you said building my own functionlaities will allow me to have 100% control ...also there seems to be many web templates for my case.. so the ideal solution will be to have a CMS and use a web template ..

Comment: so if i go with Orchard approach ,,, can i use web templetes such as the ones provided here http://www.templatemonster.com/category/construction-company-website-templates/

Comment: well I really can't check all your template content and be sure that this will work, but my answer would be yes, you can

Comment: Certainly i do not want to ask if all these templates are supported.. i just want to ask if Orachard supports adding these template to it in general. same a creating a new web site inside visual studio where you can add whatever themes and templates you want. so is this the same when using Orchards ?

Comment: sry, I thought that I allready answered on that , yes you can. You have theme (or template) and you can have your views (CSHTML). Look here http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/First-steps-into-Orchard

Comment: i read about Orchard CMS , but seems i need to chose a theme that is compatible with Orchard. so i might find a web template as the ones i provide links for ,, but these template need to be transformed into Orchard compatible theme first ,,is this correct ?

Comment: correct, see this http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/custom-orchard-themes-converting-existing-web-design-and-html-templates

Comment: so i am confused now if it is supported or if is it possible to integrate web templates inside Orchard CMS ? on you first answer you mentioned it is possible , but now seems that it is not a straight forward task is this correct ?

Comment: yes there is some work to do, but in my opinion still far less than developing your own cms :)

Comment: Your points sound valid,so i will now start learning Orchard as i find it the best choice to go with especially that it is built on asp.net mvc. but as a general question at the end; can i get templates such as the one mentioned here http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/52288.html mapped inside Orchard ? or there will be some UI components that will not be mapped 100% correctly ?  the idea of my question is to know in advance if Orchard will be able to map these templates without any limitations?and if u can mention some features that will have some limitation when mapped to Orchard?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at:

http://abundantcode.com/15-best-asp-net-based-content-management-systemscms/

Plus, out of the list:

- https://piranhacms.org/
- https:// www.mrcms.com/

Comment: @danictra but is it a bad choice if i build my own CMS features, so that end users can manage the web templete componets